# How to set mid and bottom text in bootstrap with grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to find a solution for it here, searching, etc, but nothing seems to work. Basically im trying to set the footer using grids in bootstrap but I cant figure it out how to set the class link-footer in the middle height of the div of the footer and the footer-copyright class just to send it to the bottom. Here is the idea: https://prnt.sc/q8abeb

I share with you the code clean:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 col-footer">
        <h1>aloha name</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">about me</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">contact</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-copyright text-center">© 2020 Copyright:
    <span>aloha</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I add the CSS but is not too much actually

```
footer {
background-color: #545454;
height: 200px;
}

.col-footer h1 {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size:2em;
color:white;
}

.link-footer a {
font-size:1em;
color:white;
font-weight: 600;
text-decoration: none;
}

.link-footer a:hover {
color:#4860FF;
}

.footer-copyright {
background-color: #3b3b3b;
color: #838383;

}

.footer-copyright span{
color: white;
}
```

I have tried adding margin, bottom, py, my, my-auto, etc and nothing works. Any idea??

Comment: do you mean this class? [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/)

Comment: I suggest using flexbox for this. You can get a basic understanding here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and then use the BS4 shorthand properties to quickly set the required classes

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @denkquer do you recommend me to use better flexbox than grids of bootstrap then? the tutorial looks really nice so im gonna give it a try and im gonna check if it worked.

Comment: @D4rKNiGhT Bootstraps grid system uses flexbox too. It just tries to abstract this layer from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Your Screenshot is not very helpful.

But this would work aswell:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center py-5" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-footer">
                <h1>aloha name</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 link-footer">
                <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 link-footer">
                <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">about me</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 link-footer">
                <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">projects</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 link-footer">
                <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">contact</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="footer-copyright text-center" style="margin-top: -15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">© 2020 Copyright:
            <span>aloha</span>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Make sure to add the inline css to your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer {
background-color: #545454;
height: 200px;
}

.col-footer h1 {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size:2em;
color:white;
}
.link-footer a {
font-size:1em;
color:white;
font-weight: 600;
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
}
.text-uppercase{
padding-right:2em;
}
.link-footer a:hover {
color:#4860FF;
}

.footer-copyright {
background-color: #3b3b3b;
color: #838383;
 position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width:100%;
   text-align: center;

}

.footer-copyright span{
color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer class="page-footer">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 col-footer">
        <h1>aloha name</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">about me</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 link-footer">
        <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">contact</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-copyright text-center">© 2020 Copyright:
    <span>aloha</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```